# Why aren't my flags being handled?

Tags: support, flags

I have a couple of custom moderator flags pending. That have now been pending for **3 weeks**.

What is going on with these that makes them take so long?

Here are the flags for reference:

[image: IDs scratched out to avoid the Meta-effect]

Comment: Still, there could be less moderators around during this time of the year.

Comment: @StephenLeppik They regularly take that long.  This isn't unusual at all.

Comment: @StephenLeppik It's entirely lucky you had flags handled quickly in the past, but the SO mod flag queue tends to be large and rather slow for processing.

Comment: If it would be me I'd decline the flags shown in the post - acting on the answers to closed questions *before* getting questions re-opened is waste of time (which also makes processing other flags slower... which leads to this question :) )... If you believe that your flags are valid I'd recommend asking separate question whether it is good idea.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually, the answers mentioned are completely unrelated.

Comment: My oldest pending flags are `Oct 26`, `Oct 31`, `Nov 8`... `:=)`. However I don't like to rush mods, so they will get to them when they do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rate of flag handling can vary wildly depending on how many of us are around, the kind of flag being cast, and overall timing of when the flag was cast. This last week was a U.S. holiday, so several moderators were out because of that, and I'm still getting caught up after being away the entire week before that due to a conference. Others have had things that kept them away at around the same time.

When it comes to custom flags, those can be handled at very different rates depending on their subject matter and when they were cast. All custom flags end up in one long unsorted queue, and we don't yet have built-in capabilities for sorting them by keyword. Some of us have userscripts for this, but they don't always work perfectly.

I try to triage the most important or easiest to act on flags first (plagiarism, voting fraud, trolls, spammers, highly abusive users, and so on) and leave the rest for a later pass. We currently have 625 custom flags in the queue, with the oldest being cast a month ago. We'll eventually get caught up, but we're trying to clear out the easy and important flags first.

Answer undeletion requests can usually wait a little bit, and might require a little more time to review, so I can see why those might have been deferred until later.